# What is going in in this IF-ELSE statement?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm really stuck here and it simply doesn't make any sense to me. Here's what's going on: I have an AsyncTask sending data to a server and retrieving a String response back. The String response can be two things: it can be a message telling the user that he/she is logged in if the credentials entered are correct or it can be a "FALSE" string which I use to display a notification toast to the user and take him/her back to the main activity to retry logging in.

Here is the code snippet:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {    
        String cr = "Placeholder";
        Credential cred = new Credential();

        try { cr = cred.execute().get(); } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
        catch (ExecutionException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        //tv.setText(cr);

        if (cr == "FALSE") {
            Log.d("Checking in false", cr);
            Toast.makeText(Credentials.this, "Cannot log in: wrong username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(Credentials.this, MainActivity.class));
        } else if (cr != "FALSE") {
            Log.d("Checking in true", cr);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Credentials.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_DATA, cr);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

By using the `Log.d()` static method and looking at the LogCat, I'm sure that the returned value is indeed `FALSE` if the credentials are wrong (again, it's not a boolean value, just String in all Caps). The funny thing is that the code that gets executed is the "else if" part of the snippet I have posted **but it actually logs that the returned string value is `FALSE`!** Which means (at least to me) that it should have executed the first "if" condition (that is, `if (cr == "FALSE") { }` ). But no, it keeps executing the "else if" part.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you need the else if, just else.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I was just getting desperate at that point. Turns out I had to use the equals() method as suggested by Vyger.

Comment: Cool, like you, I totally forgot about the .equals() method in Java, so don't beat yourself up about it :-)

Comment: Thanks! Little things like this can turn into quite frustrating, time-consuming tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use equals for string comparisons.

I.E:

WRONG:

```
if (cr == "FALSE") {
```

CORRECT:

```
if (cr.equals("FALSE")) {
```

Comment: Damn! That must be it! I totally forgot about this. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: This **IS** it... ;) And don't forget to correct the `else if`, too

Comment: Hehe, thank you so much! I fixed the else-if too, thanks. I was just reading about it yesterday again (to not compare Strings using == I mean) but I guess you have to waste a couple of hours on something to really learn you lesson. :) Thanks again.

Comment: Well, if you come from another language, it take some times to switch. I'm coming from VB.NET: there the concept of **==** doesn't even exist; it is everything with the **=** operator: comparisons, assignments, string comparisons...

Comment: The only two languages I have previous experience in are Quick Basic and Turbo Pascal to be honest and that's years ago. I have been studying quite a lot of Java but sometimes I get confused by little things like this.

Comment: Well, a programming language is like a martial art: you have to train, train, train, ...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (cr.contentEquals("false") {
    //your code     
} else {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't read about the contentEquals() method, I'll check it out!